# PHP -Comparing Unix Timestamp To Now

Tags: php, time, compare

I'm retrieving a unix timestamp from a DB and I want to check if this datetime has passed already.

I tried using an if statement to compare to `time()` but it always says the time has passed already.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Just some more info..to determine am/pm I'm adding 12 to the hour if its PM before running it through mktime(). (Is this right?)

It's stored in the DB as int not as any datetime types.

Comment: Try and print both DB and PHP timestamps out to visually see if perhaps the DB is adding microseconds or is not using GMT.  Second make sure both the DB and the PHP application server are on the same datetime and their internal date time's are with 1 second of each other.

Comment: I will try printing both and comparing my self. The timestamp in the DB was generated by php's mktime() and stored in the db as an "int" so I don't think it can add microseconds. Added more info to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP time could be affected by PHP's timezone. Use date_default_timezone_get() to find out what time zone you're in.

Comment: Well, it's running on a local server and I'm accessing the site on the server so I doubt the time zone is different since I'm using only one computer. Added more info to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the timezones in the DB and PHP are the same, use `NOW()` function to fill the DB column with current timestamp (the column should be of *datetime* type), then you can get the timestamp using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` MySQL function which compares against PHP's `time()` just nice.

Alternatively, you can fill the DB column with something like

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO your_table (your_date) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(" . time() . "))")
```

That should work even with timezone discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mktime` to create a UNIX timestamp, PHP is using the timezone settings to interpret what you mean by the given parameters. It's possible that you should be using `gmmktime`. It depends on how the timestamps in the database are being created; I cannot say for sure without seeing more code and having a more detailed explanation.

I generally prefer to simply store all dates as DATETIME types in the UTC (GMT) timezone. It tends to be less confusing.

> Just some more info..to determine am/pm I'm adding 12 to the hour if its PM before running it through mktime(). (Is this right?)

- 12 PM is hour 12.
- 1 PM is hour 13.

So you don't always add 12. (i.e., 12 Noon is the exception).